# Images are not showing on front end in Magento

Tags: image, magento, product

I have approx 200-300 products in store But I have a problem related products images on front end. On front end only some images are showing rest are blank.
I have already replaced all images with original but problem is still remains.

Note that all images are of more than 2500 x 2500 dimensions.

Suggest me solution.

Comment: You should use appropriate image size for every type of image: image (big), small image and thumbnail. Are you using 2500x2500 size image as a small image?

Comment: Yes for all small thumbnail and image

But in admin all images are properly showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have PHP GD's extension installed and is working correctly. This happened to me once when I moved an installation of Magento to another server.